# What would a bracket for holding 1 5/8" square post be called?

Tags: deck, hardware, brackets

For stabilizing a handrail post, using 1 5/8" square posts, I'm seeking a bracket shaped like so:

[image: square post bracket]

Where the U shaped bracket would tightly press the post against a surface.  First what might this be called, and is it a standard part?  I've tried lots of Google image searches, but so far nothing suitable has come up.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use with brackets why don't you consider the use of some 3/8" x 2.5" lag bolts installed through 7/16" holes drilled through the post. If you do this remember that for best grip of the lag bolts into the surface behind will be to drill the proper sized pilot hole. In this case the pilot drill can be 1/4" size.

[image]

Comment: Structural engineer says "not enough".  Also the bracket bears on a larger wood area.

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen something like that for 2x4 and for 4x4.

See: [Simpson Deck Post Tie DPTZ](http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/dptz.asp)

> The DPTZ Deck Post Tie products are used to attach 2x4 (DPT5Z) or 4x4 (DPT7Z) vertical posts to the side of stringers, rims or other wood members.

---

#### 2x4 Deck Post Tie

[image: 2x4 Simpson Deck Post Tie - Home Depot]

---

#### 4x4 Deck Post Tie

[image: 4x4 Simpson Deck Post Tie]

---

You could ask your "engineer" if you can make your own 2x2 tie with some strapping.

#### Simpson Strapping

[image: Simpson Coil Strapping]

---

If you gave us a better idea of what you are trying to do, maybe we could come up with a better solution than a bracket that probably doesn't exist.

---

***Opinionated aside:*** You would think that some lags or structural screws would be sufficient.

Why I think that and also the likely reason that they don't make these brackets for 2x2 (which is what you are talking about) is that the 2x2 is probably weak enough that a bracket is pointless. By that, I mean that the force needed to pull out lags or structural screws would snap the post before pulling out the fasteners, making the bracket pointless.

That and I can't imagine where a 2x2 would be counted on as any form of structural member anywhere but a balustrade.